# Classes within Coffeescript 'Namespace'

Tags: coffeescript

I found this snippet on the Coffeescript FAQ for creating simplistic namespaces ..

```
# Code:
#
namespace = (target, name, block) ->
  [target, name, block] = [(if typeof exports isnt 'undefined' then exports else window), arguments...] if arguments.length < 3
  top    = target
  target = target[item] or= {} for item in name.split '.'
  block target, top

# Usage:
#
namespace 'Hello.World', (exports) ->
  # `exports` is where you attach namespace members
  exports.hi = -> console.log 'Hi World!'

namespace 'Say.Hello', (exports, top) ->
  # `top` is a reference to the main namespace
  exports.fn = -> top.Hello.World.hi()

Say.Hello.fn()  # prints 'Hi World!'
```

That is all well and good, but I am having a great deal of trouble doing this with the `class` keyword. Such that ..

```
namespace 'Project.Something', (exports) ->
   exports.something = -> class something
    // .. code here
   exports.somethingElse = class somethingElse extends something
```

can anyone shed some light on the syntax that would accomplish this?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The trick is to create the class first

```
class MyFirstClass
  myFunc: () ->
    console.log 'works'

class MySecondClass
  constructor: (@options = {}) ->
  myFunc: () ->
    console.log 'works too'
    console.log @options
```

Then somewhere near the end of the file export all the classes than need to be exposed.

```
namespace "Project.Something", (exports) ->
  exports.MyFirstClass = MyFirstClass
  exports.MySecondClass = MySecondClass
```

Later on you can use the classes as so:

```
var firstClass = new Project.Something.MyFirstClass()
firstClass.myFunc()

var secondClass = new Project.Something.MySecondClass 
  someVar: 'Hello World!'

secondClass.myFunc()
```

Comment: There we go! It was so simple, but so frustrating at the same time. Thank you!

Comment: There should be a method that does this for you :(

Comment: Doesn't this defeat the purpose of Namespacing? Seen as MyFirstClass is now defined both in the Namespace and outside of it? @ChrisSubagio's answer seems like a more correct way to do it.

Comment: No. Coffeescript wraps that file within an anonymous function so `MyFirstClass` is not leaked to the global namespace. It's only exposed to the global namesapce through the `namespace` function.

Answer (score 24):

Even better, the class syntax allows for the name to actually be in the form of a member, so you can actually just do:

```
namespace 'Secrets', (exports) ->
  class exports.Hello
    constructor: ->
      @message = "Secret Hello!"

a = new Secrets.Hello
console.log a.message
```

Full fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Efgd/1/

Comment: This is a valid solution as well. It's really a matter of preference. I find the example above a little easier for me to understand.

Answer (score 1):

How about using something like this?

```
module =
    Hello: class Hello extends Backbone.Model
        constructor: ->
            @message = 'Hello'

    Hello2: class Hello2 extends Backbone.View
        constructor: ->
            @message = 'Hello2'
```