# how do I use coffeescript's namespace code in Node?

Tags: node.js, oop, coffeescript

related: [Classes within Coffeescript 'Namespace'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8730859/classes-within-coffeescript-namespace)

OK so after reading that post I grabbed the namespace function and put it in its own file.

`namespace.coffee`

```
namespace = (target, name, block) ->
  [target, name, block] = [(if typeof exports isnt 'undefined' then exports else window), arguments...] if arguments.length < 3
  top    = target
  target = target[item] or= {} for item in name.split '.'
  block target, top
  console.log "created namespace "+ name


root = exports ? window
root.namespace = namespace
```

and then in Repl:

```
>  namespace = require('./assets/js/namespace.js').namespace
[Function]
```

If I toString() it it's correct.

OK, so now I want to use it: `ns.coffee` (from Sandro's answer)

```
namespace = require('./namespace.js').namespace

class MyFirstClass
  myFunc: () ->
    console.log 'works'

class MySecondClass
  constructor: (@options = {}) ->
  myFunc: () ->
    console.log 'works too'
    console.log @options

namespace "Project.Something", (exports) ->
  exports.MyFirstClass = MyFirstClass
  exports.MySecondClass = MySecondClass
  console.log 'done with exports'
```

Then I run it in Repl:

> ns = require('./assets/js/ns.js')   # compiled ns.coffee
>   done with exports
>   created namespace Project.Something
>   {}

It doesn't appear to be working:

```
> ns.MyFirstClass                                              
undefined                                                      
> ns.MySecondClass                                             
undefined                                                      
> ns.Project.Something.MySecondClass                           
TypeError: Cannot read property 'Something' of undefined
```

Am I doing something wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `exports` variable is the `module.exports` *for the file you reference it from*.  So when you call `namespace`, it changes `exports` that was returned from `require`ing `namespace`, not the one that will be returned from `require`ing `ns`.

Notice how `namespace` takes 3 arguments, but the first line in it essentially makes `target` optional.  If you pass in the `target` (you probably want `exports`, or maybe `exports ? window` if this needs to run in both server and client), then it should do what you want.

Comment: It seems like if that was the case then I wouldn't see the console log messages from the namespace file, but I do: "created namespace Project.Something"

Comment: @jcollum Why not?  The arguments to `namespace` get passed through just fine.

Comment: Sure, that code is running, but it's clearly not creating the namespace or I'm calling it incorrectly.

Comment: @jcollum See my edit, which should allow you to call it with the current file structure.